# C# listbox to panel and linkbuttons

Tags: c#, database, list

I have tried learn C# and I have made my small list from database. However, if I don't want to use listbox. How I can make same thing using Panel and linkbuttons?

I tried someting like this but, I cannot set **panel.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();** or **listlb.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();** So, how I have to do it? Where I have to put DataSource or ExecuteReader?

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
List<LinkButton> listlb = new List<LinkButton>();

foreach (someting)
{
    LinkButton button = new LinkButton();
    button.Text = name;
    button.PostBackUrl = link
    panel.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Here is my example code, (which works):

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyData;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=****;Password=****;"))
{
    string query = "SELECT name, link FROM animals";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();

    var list = new ListBox();

    list.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    list.DataTextField = "name";
    //list.DataValueField = "link";
    list.DataBind();
    Controls.Add(list);
}
```

Idea is that when I click name, it opens URL.

Comment: A Panel is not for Databinding. It's a layout control. Consider adding Linkbuttons in your foreach to the Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could allows you to add controls without a ListBox

```
using (var dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    if (dReader != null) {
        while (dReader.Read()) {
            LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
            //You should change the offset if you want to edit the query
            //In your case 0 is name and 1 is link
            btn.Text = dReader.GetString(0);
            btn.PostBackUrl = dReader.GetString(1);
            panel.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was the intention to do so,

> Consider adding Linkbuttons in your foreach to the Panel.

but where I will save my **cmd.ExecuteReader();** if I don't use new **ListBox();** ?

```
var list = new ListBox(); // I replace this with what?
list.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

foreach(object item in Listbox)
{
   LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
   btn.Text = item.name;
   btn.PostBackUrl = item.link;
   panel.Controls.Add(btn);
}
Controls.Add(panel);
```

That's my problem. I don't know where I need to save my **cmd.ExecuteReader**. I have not code much C#. **Someting.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();**